# CountifS with VBA to extrernal workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am really new to VBA Macros-Functions and I would like to ask:

How i can write a function to a "Dummy" workbook in order to represent a table (starting from where my selected cell is) based on Countifs from a workbook that i select when i will run this macro.

Example:

[image: Table]

Every cell of my results contain a similar "Countifs".*This table was on my target workbook and i paste it here. I know that this can't work*

What i want to achieve is:

When i run the macro i want to select a workbookand paste the result of those countifs to my Dummy Workbook in my ActiveCell

Countifs are like this

C:C =*USE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = ok  << cell -> B2>>

C:C =*USE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = no     << cell -> B3>>

C:C =*USE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = op     << cell -> B4>>

C:C =*NOTUSE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = ok    <<  cell -> C2>>

C:C =*NOTUSE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = no     << cell -> C3>>

C:C =*NOTUSE_CWP* J:J = Relevant K:K = op    <<  cell -> C4>>

And so on.....

Please ask me to give you more details if the post is unclear.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your question related to `COUNTIFS` or are you just asking how to open a workbook, get a range of data and paste it to a sheet in another workbook?

Comment: thanks for you fast replay. My question is related to COUNTIFS.This table is the output of Countifs. I don't want this table to exist on my "Main Workbook" but i want to create those results to a dummy Workbook.So my dummy Workbook will connect to Main workbook to make the countif check and return the results. My problem is that the main workbook daily change name that's why i want to selecet it manualy.

Comment: So what you need is some code to display a 'FileOpen' dialogue and a variable to accept the return?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald You are.correct! Choose the file and get the return.But the return is 18 values

Answer (score 0):

In the source workbook you can set-up a `COUNTIFS` formula to look at another workbook. For example:

`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'["&B1&"]"&B2&"'!"&B3),B4)`

Where:

- `B1` contains name of the workbook e.g. `YourWorkbook.xlsx`
- `B2` contains name of a worksheet in the workbook in `B1` e.g. `DataSheet`
- `B3` contains name of a range of sheet in `B2` e.g. `$A$1:$A$100`
- `B4` contains value you are looking for in the range `B3` e.g. `foo`

So you can use these reference across any `COUNTIFS` formula in your workbook and also change the references if you need to update the source data for your table.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Nice approach but i have multiple ranges to check